# gem install watir - ERROR: While executing gem (Net::HTTPServerException) 407 "Proxy Authentication Required"

Tags: ruby, proxy, permissions, rubygems

This has been driving me nuts - I've looked everywhere for a solution to this over the last three days... but nothing's worked, so far.

On Monday, I was getting this error when trying to install watir:

```
C:\Users\dan>gem install watir 
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'watir' (>= 0), here is why: 
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out 
(https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

So figured it was a firewall / proxy error. To try and get around it, I used the `--http-proxy` option:

```
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin>gem install watir --http-proxy http://my.awesome.proxy:port
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPServerException)
407 "Proxy Authentication Required"
```

So then I tried running it with my username and password defined, but I've read it won't work if my password contains a special character (which it does):

```
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin>gem install --http-proxy http://myusername:mypassword@my.awesome.proxy:port watir
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPServerException)
407 "Proxy Authentication Required"
```

So then I tried set the proxy, username and password for HTTP and HTTPS using the set option like so:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=my.awesome.proxy:port
set HTTP_PROXY_USER=myusername
set HTTP_PROXY_PASS=mypassword
set HTTPS_PROXY=my.awesome.proxy:port
set HTTPS_PROXY_USER=myusername
set HTTPS_PROXY_PASS=mypassword
```

...but I'm still getting the 407 error. Any ideas?

I'm on Windows 10, my gem environment details are below:

```
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.4.2 (2017-09-14 patchlevel 198) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby24-x64/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/dan/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
     - C:/Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

@Beartech:

```
C:\Ruby24-x64>ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017

MINGW64 ~
$ openssl s_client -host rubygems.org -port 443
connect: Connection timed out
connect:errno=116
```

Comment: Can you run `ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'` and post the output in your question, also run `openssl s_client -host rubygems.org -port 443` and post that in your question also?

Comment: Also, if you visit `https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz` in your browser does it download the .gz file? Or does it give you a cert warning or error?

Comment: Hi @Beartech, sorry for the delayed response. I've added some more info to the question. And, if I go to `https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz` it does download the .gz file - though I can't install it using the `--local` option because it needs to connect to the web which gives me the same 407 response.

Comment: Well I guess the "easy" answer is change your password to something without a special character for the install then change it back.

Comment: Does your proxy use NTLM authentication? See this thread for issues with NTLM authentication: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/163889

Comment: Thanks for your help @Beartech - managed to solve it just now. I needed to use %5C instead of a backslash! I've posted the code in the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it! A colleague had similar proxy issues with Atom's plugin list so pointed me in the right direction.

The command is:

```
gem install --http-proxy http://{domain}%5C{username}:{password}@{proxy.address}:{port}/ watir
```